# Joomla Beez template, mystery CSS

Tags: css, joomla

Im looking at the Joomla Beez templates index.php file, and I come across this.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="beezDivision" headerLevel="3" />
```

What is beezDivision? Theres no mention in the related CSS, and Ive grep -in 'beezDivision' * -R with nothing resulting other than a few lines very similar to the above one showing up (all in the templates/beez/index.php file). I imagine its used somewhere internally, but havent had luck finding out what it does. Possibly something new to me for CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I havn't looked into how the style attribute is being used in the Beez template but the attribute value refers to the chrome style used to wrap the output generated by the module:

http://docs.joomla.org/What_is_module_chrome%3F

Answer (score 0):

Confirming jessedb's answer - /templates/beez/html/modules.php contains a function to generate a custom module style with the appropriate name.